# WebService (SOAP) - Remove the Protocol suffix in wsdl file

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, soap

I want to remove the Protocol suffix: Soap, SoapIn, SoapOut

> ```
> <!--<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <wsdl:definitions xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/"
> ```
>
> xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
>   xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/"
>   xmlns:tns="http://www.proiam.com/PMItemAndLocationEnquiry/"
>   xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
>   xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
>   xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/"
>   xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/"
>   targetNamespace="http://www.proiam.com/PMItemAndLocationEnquiry/"
>   xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
>         
>           
>             
>             
>               
>                 
>                   
>                 
>                 
>                 
>                 
>               
>             
>             
>             
>               
>                 
>                   
>                 
>               
>             
>             
>               
>                 
>                   
>                     
>                   
>                 
>               
>             
>             
>               
>                 
>                 
>               
>             
>             
>               
>                 
>               
>             
>             
>               
>               
>             
>             
>               
>                 
>                   
>                     
>                       
>                         
>                         
>                         
>                         
>                         
>                         
>                       
>                     
>                   
>                   
>                   
>                   
>                   
>                   
>                 
>                 
>               
>             
>             
>               
>                 
>                   
>                   
>                 
>                 
>               
>             
>             
>             
>               
>                 
>                 
>                 
>                 
>               
>             
>             
>           
>         
>         
>           
>         
>         
>           
>         
>         
>           
>         
>         
>           
>         
>         
>           
>         
>         
>           
>         
>         
>           
>         
>         
>           
>         
>         
>           
>             
>             
>           
>           
>             
>             
>           
>           
>             
>             
>           
>           
>             
>             
>           
>         
>         
>           
>           
>             
>             
>               
>             
>             
>               
>             
>           
>           
>             
>             
>               
>             
>             
>               
>             
>           
>           
>             
>             
>               
>             
>             
>               
>             
>           
>           
>             
>             
>               
>             
>             
>               
>             
>           
>         
>         
>           
>             
>           
>         
>       -->